# Dynamic row layout with CSS based on number of items

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I am wondering if there is a way with CSS Grid and/or Flexbox to create a similar dynamic grid to the following based on the number of items:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer to your question is, maybe. But on this site, we volunteer to help you fix your code. We don't write code from scratch (imagine if that were the case). Let us see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, I don't believe there's a way to achieve this without some level of javascript. That being said, here's a way to accomplish it with minimal scripting necessary.

```js
function generateBoxes(size){
  let str = "", n = size
  while(--n > -1){
    str += `<div data-size="${size}"></div>`
  }
  return str
}

function createLayout(i){
  let htmlOutput = ""
  if(i == 1) htmlOutput = generateBoxes(1)
  else {
    while(i > 2 && i != 4){
      i -= 3
      htmlOutput += generateBoxes(3)
    }

    while(i > 0){
      i -= 2
      htmlOutput += generateBoxes(2)
    }
  }
  return htmlOutput
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let i = document.querySelector('input').value || 0
    
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = createLayout(i)
})
```

```css
#output {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[data-size] {
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 1;
}
[data-size="3"] {
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
}
[data-size="2"] {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label>Input a number of boxes: <input type="number" /></label><button>Go</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```